# Just stumbled on java.util.Tripwire. It's been in Java since 1.8. Zero usages on Github. What could this be used for?

Tags: java, autoboxing

Like the title says, is `java.util.Tripwire` just an old JVM utility that hasn't been cleaned up?  Interestingly, the Javadoc is not even public for some reason.  The brief Javadoc in the source code says this:

> - Utility class for detecting inadvertent uses of boxing in
>     {@code java.util} classes.  The detection is turned on or off based on
>     whether the system property {@code org.openjdk.java.util.stream.tripwire} is
>     considered {@code true} according to {@link Boolean#getBoolean(String)}.
>
> This should normally be turned off for production use.
>
> @apiNote
>     Typical usage would be for boxing code to do:
>
> ```
>  {
>       if (Tripwire.ENABLED)
>           Tripwire.trip(getClass(), "{0} calling PrimitiveIterator.OfInt.nextInt()");
>  }
> ```

It feels like something that shouldn't be used.  It uses `sun.util.logging`, which I didn't even know was still around.  And, if I wanted to use it, would I have to add that snippet of code everywhere the app *might* be doing autoboxing?

Has anybody used this for something useful?

Comment: Is it publicly accessible, or package-protected?

Comment: Ah, good point. It's package level, which means only internal java.util classes can use it. I guess that kinda answers my question.

Answer (score -2):

I can think of a few uses for it and none of them are very palatable. Not least of which would be a method of delivering code fragments to a system that activate when certain strings are detected (a website visit, a certain phone number....) and then assembled to execute a code environment that the user has no idea about whilst logging the activity to destinations unknown whilst totally avoiding the AV.